Unsuccessful in parallelizing a string decomposition
I am categorizing a very large set of indexed strings that, due to size and complexity, takes long enough to desire to execute this via parallelization.
The below is a simplification, not representative of the actual functionality and may therefore not come across as intuitive. It does however capture the emerging issue I am failing to understand and therefore resolve.
The actual situation has 8.5 million Associations packed in a Dataset and about 20 ways to segment the strings via StringSplit.
What I’ve tried without success (code snippets later):
Parallalize which provides the outcome but defaults to sequential processing (without providing a warning);
ParallelEvaluate takes longer and produces the same result just 8 times (the number of parallel kernels);
ParallelMap throws an error;
ParallelSubmit suffers from a RecursionLimit for certain - but not all – scenario’s. I cannot replicate the succesfull executions as it seems random (in a few cases it works, but often not).
Errors thrown by ParallelSubmit are:

RecursionLimit::reclim2 :  Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of Developer`HoldSymbolQ[v].
RecursionLimit::reclim2 :  Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of OwnValues[v].

The (simplified) code:
Start with generating a simulation of the input file csvImport:
ClearAll["Global`*"];

simulationLength = 8000;

index = RandomInteger[{1, 30}, {simulationLength, 4}];

files = StringJoin /@ Transpose[{
     RandomChoice[{"file://", "https://", "A:/", "B:/", ""}, simulationLength],
     RandomChoice[{"Downloads/", "Movies/" , "Scans/", "Documents/", "Desktop/"}, simulationLength],
     RandomChoice[DictionaryLookup[], simulationLength],
     StringJoin["[", #, "]"] & /@ ToString /@ RandomChoice[Range[25], simulationLength],
     RandomChoice[{".pdf", ".xlsx", ".ppt", ".docx"}, simulationLength]
     }];


csvImport = Append[{index}, files] // Transpose;

csvImport = Dataset@(AssociationThread[{"id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "form"} -> Flatten[#]] & /@ csvImport) // Sort;

Define a few Patterns
hyperlinkPatt = "://";
filePatt = ":/";
localPatt = "/";
typePatt = ".pdf" | ".xlsx" | ".ppt" | ".docx";

The set up a shared valuable and distribution of definitions via SharedValuable and DistributeDefinitions:
v = 1; SetSharedVariable[v];
DistributeDefinitions[v, w, csvImport, hyperlinkPatt, filePatt, localPatt, typePatt];

The attempt via Parallelize looks like:
Parallelize[collect = Reap@Map[
     <|Rule["link", w = Values[#[[;; 4]]]], 
       "form" -> StringSplit[Normal[#[["form"]]], {
          
          hyper__ ~~ hyperlinkPatt ~~ folder__ ~~ localPatt ~~ 
            fileName__ ~~ "[" ~~ version__ ~~ "]" ~~ type : typePatt :>
            First[Sow[{v++, hyper, folder, fileName, version, type, 
              w}]],
          
          folder__ ~~ localPatt ~~ fileName__ ~~ "[" ~~ version__ ~~ 
            "]" ~~ type : typePatt :> 
           First[Sow[{v++, "local", folder, fileName, version, type, 
              w}]]
          }]|> &, csvImport]];

This produces the correct output but is not run on parallel kernels.
The attempt via ParallelSubmit looks like:
exampletable = Table[ParallelSubmit[{i}, Reap@Map[
    <|Rule["link", w = Values[#[[;; 4]]]], "form" -> StringSplit[Normal[#[["form"]]], 
{
         hyper__ ~~ hyperlinkPatt ~~ folder__ ~~ localPatt ~~ 
           fileName__ ~~ "[" ~~ version__ ~~ "]" ~~ type : typePatt :>
           First[Sow[{v++, hyper, folder, fileName, version, type, 
             w}]],
         
         folder__ ~~ localPatt ~~ fileName__ ~~ "[" ~~ version__ ~~ 
           "]" ~~ type : typePatt :> 
          First[Sow[{v++, "local", folder, fileName, version, type, 
             w}]]
         }
]|> &, i]], 
{i, Dataset /@ Partition[csvImport // Normal, 1000]}]

collect = WaitAll[exampletable]

This starts up the available kernels. Occasionally succeeds but most often throws recursion limit errors: I have not been able to replicate the successful cases.

RecursionLimit::reclim2 :  Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of Developer`HoldSymbolQ[v].
RecursionLimit::reclim2 :  Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of OwnValues[v].

I will not post the other attempts, as I assume they all suffer from a similar lack of understanding on how this should work. Genuinely appreciative if someone could explain what I am doing wrong.

My first thought is to nix the shared variables (tends to defeat the efficiency of parallel evaluation, anyway) and sow {$KernelID, v++} instead of just v++. It seemed likely to me that the order doesn't matter; if it does, then ignore. You can process the {$KernelID, v++} indices after you collect them. (Actually, if order matters, sowing the time is probably more efficient than shared variables.)

@Michael E2: Thank you, that is a neat solution to speed-up and avoid the collection issue. Another issue is that I distributed csvImport to all Kernels, which defeats the purpose of the construct.
If I fix both it works.
